# Making Loop Cuts On Same Mesh on Individual areas simultaneously

Tags: modeling

I have made on my mesh using the individual origin option some inner extruded circles . what i'm trying to do is, add loop cuts in the inner section of the holes. The problem is, I have to do it one by one adding the loop cuts. Is there an option where the loop cuts can be applied simultaneously in all the holes?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You can select all the edges what you want to cut (with select similar menu or border selection tool from an appropriate view in wireframe mode) then subdivide them at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *Knife project* for this.

1. Add a plane, with edges where you want the cuts
2. Switch to *Orthographic* mode
3. Use *Mesh > Knife Project* and check *Cut through*

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jachym, great tip!

Kind regards.

Comment: Glad to be of help :).